# Excel Olap Pivot Table - Create calculated measure in MDX that shows difference to first filtered member taking into account current filters

Tags: excel, pivot-table, mdx

I have built a PivotTable in Excel365 which is based on an OLAP Cube. In the Pivot Table, I filter the customers for which I want to show the price for the filtered products. The price is a measure created in the original OLAP Cube [msrPrice].

In the Excel Pivot Table, I'd like to show the price difference for each product from each of the filtered customers compared to the first filtered customer (in the screenshot marked in green).

I usually don't use MDX but have to use it in this case since the pivot table is based on an OLAP cube (and the usual calculated fields & items don't appear to work on pivot tables based on OLAP cubes).

I'd very much appreciate your help in guiding me on my Odyssee to the right MDX statement. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example below

```
with member  
measures.t
as 
([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
/AXIS(0).item(0))*100

select 
{
([Customer].[Education].[Education],{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.t})
}
on columns,
{
[Customer].[Country].[Country]
}
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Hi Moaz, thank you for your example, it has helped to get the the right formula in Excel:

t = ( [Measures].[Price] / AXIS(0).item(0) ) - 1.

However, when I re-arrange the customers, the calculation doesn't seem to update the reference point. For example, in your example, if I manually move "Graduate Degree" to the beginning of the table (i.e. before "Bachelors"), then the reference point for the measure would remain to be "Bachelors". How could I get the measure to adjust the reference point dynamically as the user moves the desired reference customer to the beginning of the table?

Comment: It can be made dynamic with respect to position but then you need to decide which item you want to consider as your base item. w.r.t my example if you chose Graduate Degree, it will always be that. "([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
/sum([Customer].[Education].&[Graduate Degree],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]))*100"

Comment: Hi Moaz, thanks for your advice, but I'm afraid I'm still not able to re-produce it. I don't have hierarchies defined in my dataset, so I have adjusted your formula as follows for my case: ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] / sum([Education].&[Graduate Degree],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]))*100
However, this only produces a result for the column "Graduate Degree" in your screenshot above. For the other columns, I get no result (#NUM in Excel). I've tried to adjust the formula, but unfortunately couldn't work out what could be the problem. Would you have any idea?

Comment: What are you refering to as " I don't have hierarchies defined in my dataset".Secondly If you have mangement studio, run the query on that first?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have management studio; the cube comes from PowerBI. In Excel, my PivotTable is based on the PowerBI cube (via the "Analyse in Excel" function from PowerBI). I'm not at all in the MDX world usually, so I'm afraid I may not always be able to use the right jargon.

Comment: With hierarchy, I mean that it seems to me you have a certain hierarchy set up: [Customer].[Education].&[Graduate Degree]. So within the dimension "Customer", there is the dimension "Education", and probably others. In my case, I don't have that. To stay with the example, I just have a column labelled "Education".